# Populate UIPickerView with images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm trying to populate a UIPickerView with images.
Here is where i create programmatically the PickerView and i fill a `NSMutableArray` with 35 images called 1.png, 2.png ..., 35.png

```
@interface ShowImagesPVC () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayOfImages;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for(int i = 1; i < 36; i++){
        NSString *tmpString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i];
        [_arrayOfImages addObject:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tmpString]]];
    }

    UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, 0, 315, 200)];
    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.dataSource = self;
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myPickerView];
}
```

now i've implemented these methods

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    return [_arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _arrayOfImages.count;
}
```

The problem is that the UIPicker is created but it's empty, so i tried to `NSLog` the method `- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view` and it seems it's never called.

Any idea why?

Comment: delegate and data source are properly set?

Comment: i'm setting them just after the allocation of the `UIPicker` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Where are you doing alloc+init of `_arrayOfImages`?

Comment: it's a property, i'm editing the post

Comment: That just declares the variable, it doesn't alloc+init (instantiate) it.  Also, if it's a property, it's better to work with it using self.arrayOfImages instead of the backing instance variable.  So do `self.arrayOfImages = [NSMutableArray array];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
_arrayOfImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i < 36; i++){
        NSString *tmpString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i];
        [_arrayOfImages addObject:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tmpString]]];
    }

    UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, 0, 315, 200)];
    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.dataSource = self;
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myPickerView];
}
```